# How to access something in the global namespace with the same name as something in a module?

Tags: namespaces, typescript

For example:

```
declare function foo(x : string, y : boolean) : string;

module Bar {
    export function foo(x : string) { return ???.foo(x, true); }
}
```

How can I access the global `foo` from anywhere inside `Bar` (where a raw `foo` reference will implicitly reference `Bar.foo`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a good way to do this.

Technically you could write `window['foo']`, but this will break in runtimes where the global object is not called `window`.